# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with Angular 6 and redirect

Tags: angular

I can see there is tons of posts on this subject, but mostly related to async service calls. I have an app component that takes care of login to Azure AD. When a user clicks login they are redirected to the login page of Azure and redirected back to a component called AuthCallBack. The AuthCallBack will call a method on the AppComponenet that simply sets a boolean value called userIsLoggedIn and I use this in a ngIf. I get the following error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Because its not some kind of http async call I dont have the subscripe option, what todo?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td routerLink="/">Login page</td>
    <td routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</td>
    <td (click)="login()">Login</td>
    <td (click)="logout()">Logout</td>
    <td><span *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn">Logged in</span></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

AppComponent

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  config = {
    tenant: 'xx-a8b0-4555-97b3-70001a6a7448',
    clientId: 'xx-65b4-4914-905c-aecc3e9197f5',
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/authcallback/",
    logOutUri: "http://localhost:4200",
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200",
    endpoints: {
      "http://localhost:63126/": "xx-65b4-4914-905c-aecc3e9197f5"
    }};

  userIsLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private adalService: AdalService,private router: Router)
  {
    this.adalService.init(this.config); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {     
  }

  handleWindowCallback()
  {    
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    this.userIsLoggedIn = this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;

  }

  login()
  {   
    this.adalService.login();
  }

  logout()
  {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }
}
```

AuthComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-callback',
  templateUrl: './authcallback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authcallback.component.css']
})
export class AuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent,private router: Router, private adalService: AdalService, private _zone: NgZone) { }

   ngOnInit() {

    this.appComponent.handleWindowCallback();

    //this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this._zone.run(
        () => this.router.navigate(['/'])
      );
    }, 200);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parent (appComponent) already have CD (change detection) cycle, than child component change parent's state. In dev mode - another CD come and check that nothing was changed from previous CD cycle (there error will be thrown).

We have a hacks:

-wrap in **setTimeout**, changes will be applied in new CD cycle.

```
// AuthComponent
setTimeout(()=>this.appComponent.handleWindowCallback(), 0);
```

-Call ChangeDetectorRef.**detectChanges** in parent component

```
// AppComponent
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

handleWindowCallback(){
  /* some code */
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test it asap. Why the timeout part?

Comment: You are welcome. But don't overuse as we trigger additional CD cycle, it can impact performance.